# Delete query really slow - for largish amounts of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with data for 24million users and I want to purge 23/24ths of the data evenly across all of the tables.

The delete statements are taking hours, is there anything I can do to improve the efficency of these query:

```
delete from [feedback] where [key]   %24<>0 and [key]  not in (50697,9179, 19392753, 3780,14095, 455141,455144,1576550,719307706,10233,706507,315321,2998138,19275591,73037336,23371,11904062,08496,71959,79765,9969,02315,1850,666824,32289,826578,66284,718017,85204,192179,9406787,469844,9843,13801850,8575204,8927569)
```

Comment: May be you can add a bit column to your table and do an update for the 'not in' ids. And probably for '%24<>0'. Finally you can just go through the new created flag. But if you'll do this, don't use 'not in', use equal instead. One query for one id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you intend to keep just 1/24th of the data, it will be quicker to select that data out into an alternative location, truncate the original table and copy it back.

If key constraints / operational constraints prevent this, then you should batch the deletions into chunks into a number of thousand rows per deletion, such as 10k rows per deletion and loop that command, to avoid one very large transaction (which is what is occuring with a single delete statement.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can, consider dropping unused indexes and keys before performing deletes.
The time updating indexes can be considerable.
Don't forget to re-create the indexes when you are finished.

Answer (score 1):

The scalable way (i.e. it doesn't matter how many or what percent of your data is being deleted) to do this is to "chunk up" your deletes. `DELETE` is a logged action, which means that before the rows are actually deleted, they are first written to the log file, and for 24 million rows that could be a fairly big *single* write.  Here's the basic template (untested, beware typos):

```
DECLARE @HowManyLastTime int

SET @HowManyLastTime = 1

WHILE @HowManyLastTime <> 0
 BEGIN
    DELETE top (10000)
     from [feedback] where [key]   %24<>0 and [key]  not in (50697,9179, 19392753, 3780,14095, 455141,455144,1576550,719307706,10233,706507,315321,2998138,19275591,73037336,23371,11904062,08496,71959,79765,9969,02315,1850,666824,32289,826578,66284,718017,85204,192179,9406787,469844,9843,13801850,8575204,8927569) 

    SET @HowManyLastTime = @@rowcount
 END
```

(10000 is an arbitrarily picked number, do some testing on various sizes to see what works best for your table.)

Comment: I get the idea, but for reference  `DELETE top 10000` is not valid syntax

Comment: I stand corrected! The appropriate parentheses have been added. This does and will work with SQL 2005 and up, but (I believe) will not work in SQL 2000 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Will going the other way help?

```
CREATE Table FeedBack2 AS
SELECT * FROM Feedback
WHERE Key % 24 = 0
AND Key IN (50697,9179, 19392753, 3780,14095, 455141,455144,1576550,719307706,10233,706507,315321,2998138,19275591,73037336,23371,11904062,08496,71959,79765,9969,02315,1850,666824,32289,826578,66284,718017,85204,192179,9406787,469844,9843,13801850,8575204,8927569)

TRUNCATE TABLE Feedback

INSERT INTO Feedback
SELECT * FROM Feedback2

DROP Table Feedback2
```

EDIT: The SQL above isn't precise. But I hope you will get the idea based on the above.